# With the Google API is there anyway to get all of the cities in a state, and all of the towns in a city?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to build an application where a user can "drill-down" so to speak to find a location. So if they click on "US" it should show all of the states, and if they click a state it should show all of the cities. I have looked at the Google Places API, and I'm not exactly sure what the best method is. I thought about using bounds but I feared it would not be accurate because bounds works off of a rectangle. Not the actual city or state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no any Google Maps API that can return a list of cities in the state. The Google APIs does not work this way, they are not like a database search.

You can try a [Places API autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete), but this API returns up to 5 suggestions when you are typing a text. You cannot define a strict filter by city or state, you can only bias result to certain view port.